# How does the Soulknife's Bladeskills Dual Imbue and Powerful Strikes work together with Psychic Strike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

How does the [Soulknife's](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/) [Bladeskills](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/blade-skills/) Dual Imbue and Powerful Strikes work together with [Psychic Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/#TOC-Psychic-Strike-Su-)?

> Dual Imbue: When utilizing multiple mind blades, the soulknife may charge both blades with her psychic strike ability at the same time (including when expending her focus to charge her psychic strike). However, her psychic strike damage is reduced by 1d8 when using this option. Damage remains normal when each weapon is charged separately.

and

> Powerful Strikes: The soulknife’s psychic strike deals an additional 1d8 damage.

My current Soulknife at Lv6 has a Psychic Strike of 1d8, with Powerful Strikes it becomes a 2d8; but I also have Dual Imbue. Does that become a 1d8 per mind blade then since Dual Imbue reduced the Psychic Strike dice by one? What happens at Lv7 when my Psychic Strike becomes 2d8, will the combination of Dual Imbue and Powerful Strikes remain 1d8 each or will it be 2d8 each since Powerful Strikes RAW says "psychic strike deals an additional 1d8 damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psychic strike adds +*X*d8 to your damage. Powerful strikes adds +1 to *X*. Dual imbue adds +(*X*−1)d8 damage to each of your mind blades. So in combination you get to add +[(*X*+1)−1]d8, or, equivalently, +[(*X*−1)+1]d8, to each of your mind blades. Both orders result in +*X*d8 being added to your mind blades. In effect, dual imbue and powerful strikes cancel one another out with respect to the amount of damage, but you get to keep the benefit of dual imbue and apply +*X*d8 to both mind blades.

So with both, at 6th level, that would be 1d8 on each mind blade. At 7th level, 2d8 on each mind blade.

Comment: as usual KR you save me from math problems.